# Como fazer um JFrame retornar uma instancia de um determinado objeto?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Tenho um `JFrame` chamado *JFrameCadastroPessoa* que possui apenas dois campos nome e apelido, como mostra a imagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**JFrameCadastroPessoa:**

```
public class JFrameCadastroPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     private Pessoa  pessoa = new Pessoa();

    //codigos gerados automaticamente

    //O código do botão salvar é o seguinte: 
    private void jBSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

            pessoa.setNome(jTFNome.getText());  
            pessoa.setApelido(jTFApelido.getSelectedText());

    }
   private void jBLimparActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTFNome.setText("");
        jTFApelido.setText("");
    }                                        

    public Pessoa salvar() {

        return pessoa;
    }

}
```

**Classe Pessoa**

```
    public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

        String nome;
        String apelido;

        public Pessoa() {
        }

        public Pessoa(String nome, String apelido) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.apelido = apelido;
        }

       //getters and setters


  public String toString() {
        return " { nome=" + nome + ", apelido=" + apelido + '}' + "\n";
    }
}
```

**ExibePessoa**

```
  public class ExibePessoa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrameCadastroPessoa frame = new JFrameCadastroPessoa();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
         pessoa = frame.salvar();
        System.out.println(pessoa.toString());
    }
}
```

Quero saber porque ele sempre exibe o resultado como :

```
 { nome=null, apelido=null}
```

Gostaria de exibir os dados que eu inseri no frame `JFrameCadastroPessoa`.

O que devo fazer para retornar esse objeto na classe ExibePessoa?

O problema é que quando eu rodo a classe ExibePessoa no console ela já vai logo imprimindo { nome=null, apelido=null} na saida antes mesmo de eu inserir os dados no frame!!!

Usando o `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` na classe ExibePessoa eu consigo o resutado esperado mas queria usar mesmo era o `JFrame`!!

Sei que isso tem uma resposta muito obvia mas já tentei de tudo , e é de meu conhecimento que seria mais plausível resolver as coisas simplesmente dentro da classe `JFrameCadastroPessoa` e resolver tudo no metodo `private void jBSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`  , mas realmente preciso da solução de forma que o resultado venha do metodo salvar() que retorna uma Pessoa.

Comment: Substitua isso `Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();` por isso `Pessoa pessoa = frame.salvar();;`

Comment: @diegofm  Obrigado pela atenção ,mas já fiz isso!! Dá no mesmo!O que seria EDT?

Comment: Tem outro problema no seu código, você não está iniciando dentro da EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você chama `JFrameCadastroPessoa frame = new JFrameCadastroPessoa();`, o objeto *Pessoa* é criado com os atributos nulos na classe do JFrame, e a JRE segue o fluxo normal, executando todas as linhas do seu main sem interrupção, e quando chega em `System.out.println(pessoa.toString());`, ela exibe o objeto criado na sua classe `JFrameCadastroPessoa`, com as propriedades nulas.

Você deve adicionar a exibição dentro do actionperformed para que seja exibido apenas ao clicar no botão, desta forma:

```
private void jBSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        pessoa.setNome(jTFNome.getText());  
        pessoa.setApelido(jTFApelido.getSelectedText());
        System.out.println(pessoa.toString());
}
```

Aqui sim, será exibido exatamente o que for digitado nos campos.

---

## Update

Após os comentários, eu criei um exemplo onde você pode usar um JOptionPane customizado, passando um JPanel para ele:

```
public class ExibePessoa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pessoa pessoa;

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel lbNome = new JLabel("Nome:");
        JTextField txtNome = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel lbApelido = new JLabel("Apelido:");
        JTextField txtApelido = new JTextField(20);
        p1.add(lbNome);
        p1.add(txtNome);
        p2.add(lbApelido);
        p2.add(txtApelido);
        panelPrincipal.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelPrincipal.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panelPrincipal, "Acesso Restrito", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        pessoa = new Pessoa(txtNome.getText(), txtApelido.getText());
        
        System.out.println(pessoa.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu realmente queria retornar um objeto do tipo Pessoa a partir desse Frame, sua explicação esta inexoravelemnte correta, esotu ciente  do codigo acima! Mas esse codigo de minha pergunta faz parte de um contexto maior em  um projeto onde uso Socktes e eu preciso retornar aquele objeto pessoa mesmo!!

Comment: @PenaPintada você quer passar para outro frame? Se sim, basta fazer a outra tela receber um objeto do tipo pessoa e passar para a outra tela dentro do actionPerformed, algo assim: `Frame2 = new JFrame(pessoa);`  e na outra tela vc pode receber normalmente.

Comment: Não quero passar para outro frame não mas eu preciso do objeto pessoa na classe ExibePessoa , eu coloquei o System.out.println só para exemplificar! Se quiser eu posso colocar o código no github!! Parece brincadeira a essa altura do campeonato eu não saber retornar esse objeto na   nossa classe ExibePessoa!!

Comment: @PenaPintada essa chamada vem de outra tela ou esta tela de cadastro é a unica do seu projeto?

Comment: Essa tela é  realmente Unica. Eu bolei esse exemplo exatamente para simplificar a questão!! Pos geralmente quando a gente lida com frames  usamos  o MVC  e chamamos fachadas e DAOS e tudo segue as mil maravilhas , mas esse exemplo de deixou em um beco sem saída!! Toda estrutura do projeto foi colocado aqui! O  outro projeto maior eu abstrai , pois resolveria o problema por lá se resolvesse esse nosso impasse em questão!!

Comment: @PenaPintada como voce disse na pergunta, o problema é que o JOptionPane funciona de forma que, enquanto estiver aberto, ele "trava" o restante da execução, diferente do JFrame, que continua executando após renderizar a tela.

Comment: Isso mesmo , nessa solução mencionada ele trava e dá certo(usando o JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ), mas quando tento fazer o mesmo usando o  JFrame  não!! O que devo confessar me deixou sem terra debaixo dos pés!!

Comment: @PenaPintada você sabe que pode criar um JOptionPane customizado, com essa cara do jframe? Talvez seja melhor opção.

Comment: Exatamente , o problema é que quando estava procurando meus exemplos  de JOptionPane customizados me deparei com toneladas de projetos e no momento está difícil de encontrar , sei sim que é possível customizar , mas no momento, vou lhe ser sincero não tenho a menor ideia de como customizá-lo, esqueci completamente!! Se souber, por favor  poste o código, e a sua será a resposta final!! Ultimamente   venho trabalhando apenas com projetos com interface web!! Parei de treinar SWING, infelizmente!!

Comment: @PenaPintada olha a atualização. Lembrando que você pode configurar o tamanho do textfield, alterando o 20, eu fiz aqui e ficou meio desalinhado kkk

Comment: Cara muito bom! Eu atualizei o  meu projeto aqui com o código e deu certo, então eu encapsulei a  sua solução com utilizando o Panel em uma classe chamada Chamada PanelCadastro que possui dois metodos:  criarPanel()  e retornaPessoa(); Ficou muito bom!! Valeu!!